# Filter dates stored as int on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have several documents on MongoDB collection that were created with an invalid date value and have it currently as:

```
"UpdateDate " : Date(-62135596800000)
```

I want to filter those documents, but my query is not returning any data:

```
db.MyCollection.find({UpdateDate : Date(-62135596800000)})
```

How can I filter my collection to retrieve those documents?

Comment: Try `db.MyCollection.find({UpdateDate : new Date(-62135596800000)})`

Comment: Maybe you can verify the data type of that "invalid date data" using the: [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/) and update your post.

Comment: Thanks @RubénVega the new keyword made it work. If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you need to build a proper Date object. This may be different depending on what languaje or drivers are you using to query, but in JS just using `new Date()` should work.

```
db.MyCollection.find({UpdateDate : new Date(-62135596800000)})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cant reproduce what the value need to be , luckily the date when you have inserted the document for the first time you can extract and update from the document _id as follow:

```
db.getCollection('MyCollection').update({ UpdateDate : new Date(-62135596800000) 
},
  [
{ "$set": { "UpdateDate": { $toLong: { $toDate: "$_id" }}}}
 ],
 { "multi" : true}
 )
```

This is with the assumption that you havent customized the default _id